# Netbeans Build Error upgrade-to-cordova-project

Tags: netbeans, cordova

i am trying to build a sample HTML5 Application with Netbeans/Cardova.

Cardova: 3.4.0-0.1.0
Netbeans: 7.4

Reproducing:

Device: Cordova Android Device

1. Press Build
2. Window "Create Cordova Resources and rename site root to 'www'?"
   Answer With "OK"
3. Output:

`ant -f D:\\phonegap\\CordovaMapsSample\\nbproject -Dandroid.target.device.arg=run -Denv.DISPLAY=:0.0 "-Dupdate.task.jar=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NetBeans 7.4\\webcommon\\ant\\extra\\org-netbeans-modules-cordova-projectupdate.jar" -Dandroid.sdk.home=D:\\androidsdk -Dandroid.build.target=android-19 -Dstart.file=index.html -Dandroid.project.activity=CordovaMapsSample -Dconfig=android_1 "-Dios.certificate.name=iPhone Developer" -Dsite.root=www_nb_temp "-Dcordova.version=3.4.0-0.1.0
" sim-android
check-android-template:
check-cordova-version:
check-cordova-project:
upgrade-to-cordova-project:
cordova.cmd -d create . com.coolappz.CordovaMapsSample CordovaMapsSample
Path already exists and is not empty: D:\phonegap\CordovaMapsSample
Creating a new cordova project with name "CordovaMapsSample" and id "com.coolappz.CordovaMapsSample" at location "D:\phonegap\CordovaMapsSample"
D:\phonegap\CordovaMapsSample\nbproject\build.xml:78: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`

That's it :/ 
Please Help me!

Comment: From what I get out of it is that wherever you're trying to put the project, that location already exists and has files in it.  If I remember correctly, you need to specify a new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try with with NetBeans 8.0 RC1, If I remember correctly, there was some change related to project structure in latest Cordova and NetBeans 7.4 might not be working with it.

To download 8.0 RC1, visit [this page](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/)